# Given curve is $y=x^2-1$, and $A(0,y_{1}),B(1,y_{2})$. Determine point $M$ between $A$ and $B$ so the area $AMB$ has maximum value.

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

I have found the equation for line between $A$ and $B$:
$$y=x-1$$

Equation for tangent is:
$$y=x-\frac{5}{4}$$

Coordinates of point $M(\frac{1}{2},\frac{-3}{4})$

Because the area $AMB$ is approximation of a triangle, we need normal from $M$ to line $AB$ (Langrange's theorem is recommended).

I don't know how to find coordinates of that point (normal line from $M$ to $AB$)

Comment: What does "between" mean? Does it have to be in the curve?

Comment: @cronos2 Yes, point lies on the curve

Comment: Are you saying that the $x$-coordinate of point $M$ is between $0$ and $1$? And is the figure $AMB$ a triangle or another shape? And are you asking us to find point $M$ or to use your $M$ and find the point on the normal?

Comment: @ Rory Daulton  Yes, $x$ and $y$ coordinates are between $0$ and $1$. But I have found the point $M$. I am interested in how to find a point $C$ which will with point $M$ form normal line on $AB$

Comment: Like $C=tA+(1-t)B,\; (M-C)\cdot(B-A)=0$ and solve for $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The point you're looking for is of the form $(a, a^2-1)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Now the projection of that $M$ will be some $(p, p-1): (p-a, p-a^2) \cdot (1, 1) = 0 \implies p = \frac{a^2+a}{2}$.

Now calculate its norm, find the triangle's area in terms of $a$ and derivate that expression to find a maximum (you will also get two minimums for $a=0,1$)